# WebDriverWait timer resets between tests?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```java
// setting timeout to a FULL MINUTE
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
// First, click the usermenu
WebElement userMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("UserMenu")));
userMenu.click();
WebElement adminPortal = driver.findElement(By.id("AdminPortals"));
action.moveToElement(adminPortal);
action.perform();

// Wait for secondary menu to become available
WebElement portal = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(portalId)));
portal.click();
```

Basically, "UserMenu" is a drop-down, and there's a hover-over expansion menu "AdminPortals". The above code simulates (in Selenium, the action of clicking on an item in the expanded menu.

The question I have is in relation to the timeout period. When does it start counting down? I assume it is when I use wait.until(). And I assume it stops counting once True is returned by ExpectedConditions? And, the real question is: If I use the same "wait" twice, as I have here, does the 60 seconds reset as the limit between each use, or does it restart counting where it stopped before?

So, if the first wait took 2 seconds, and the second wait took 3 seconds, will the timeout for the third call to wait.until() be 55 seconds, or reset to 60?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it starts counting down when you call the `until` method.  When you instantiate a new `WebDriverWait` object and specify a timeout it sets up a clock, so each time you call the `util` method on that object it will continue to count down the *same timer*.  It doesn't reset the timer each time it returns.  If you want the timer to reset you will need to create new WebDriverWait objects.

This is really unclear in the documentation.  I had to look at the code to figure out what was going on.  The logic is actually inherited from the FluentWait class.  Here's the source code link I looked at:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java

So, if the first wait took 2 seconds, and the second wait took 3 seconds, the timeout for the third call to `wait.until()` will be 55 seconds.

Comment: Awesome. That clarifies everything, and may explain why I'm getting unexpected exceptions thrown.